# jQuery: $.ajax inside if-statement allways called (should not!)

Tags: jquery, ajax, if-statement

Good Morning everybody

---

EDIT: Sorry bout the written mistakes! The idea was to show a minimal example and i tipped it specially in here. But the main idea should be understandable.

I also tried to store the "outer" ajax result into an array. That works fine but the problem is the same. I guess that the problem is the asynchronouse handling of the different ajax calls. Because of that i get the result sometimes "twice" instead of two different results and i get the result too late.

### I guess that i have to use the queue ore something like this.

I have a problem with my jQuery script. The minimal looks something like this:

```
// - First call "outer" .ajax
$.ajax({
  type: "GET", url: "FILE.xml", dataType: "xml",
  success: function( outerxml ) {

    $( outerxml ).find("content").each( function() {

      var x = $(this).attr('id'); // - Get id attribute
      if ( x == 'doit' )
      {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET", url: "FILE.xml", dataType: "xml",
          success: function( innerxml ) {
             alert("inner ajax");
             ...
          } // - End of inner success
        }); // - End of inner .ajax
      }
      alert("end of if statement");

    }); // - End .find("content")

  } // - End outer success
}); // - End outer .ajax
```

Please note that the if-condition is "false" (x != "doit"). The problem is that the script runs to the end of the if-statement (i get the "end of if statement"-alert) and AFTERWARDS the script calls the ajax (but it should not). I get the "inner ajax"-alert after the "end of if statement" alert.

I cannot find a solution or the problem at all. Are there some hints? :) Please.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's that `type="GET"` inside an object? It should be `type: "GET"` on both cases. Also, a missing parentheses here `}) // - End .find("content")`.

Comment: Additionally, I'm not certain what is `this` bound to inside the `success` callback. It might be wise to store `$(this)` inside a variable prior to calling the first `$.ajax`.

Comment: If you're getting the "inner ajax" alert then the Ajax request is being sent. Therefore, for some item in the `find("content")` list, `x=='doit'` must be true.

Comment: Hi, could you show the content of the `FILE.xml` file you're `GET`ting? As for your comment about the order of `alert`s: I'm pretty sure this is the expected behavior, since the ajax call is performed asynchronously. So my guess would be: the first `<content>` node in your xml file does have the "doit" id, and this happens: 1) your ajax call is performed, 2) the "end of if statement" alert is fired, 3) the response arrives and the success function is called, resulting in the "inner ajax" alert. But to be sure... we have to see the XML :)

Answer (score 0):

You have an `if` statement on one line, and an opening brace on the next line. I think you're running into JavaScript's most evil "feature" here: [automatic semicolon insertion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Whitespace_and_semicolons).

Basically, you have

```
if ( x == 'doit' )
{
    // code
}
```

But it is being parsed as

```
if (x == 'doit'); // <-- note semicolon inserted here

// Now this block is logically disconnected from the if statement
{
    // code
}
```

The moral of the story is to be very careful about where you introduce line breaks in JavaScript code, because the language wants to treat end-of-line as end-of-statement whenever it can.